# Spring Scheduling - Cron expression for every month end at 11PM?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cron, quartz-scheduler

I would like to run cron expression at 11:10 pm of very month ending. I am trying to write by following link [A Guide To Cron Expressions](https://www.baeldung.com/cron-expressions) but I am unable to write. Sample code is below is this will work fine.

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 10 23 L * ? *")
public void scheduleTaskWithCronExpression() {
    System.out.println("Cron Task");
}
```

Comment: try with 23 not 22

Comment: @sajib I just updated my question once . Is this code will work fine.

Comment: yes. it will work. i gave link. check here

Comment: Yeah, Thank you. I updated my code with working cron expression

Answer (score 5):

Try with this:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 10 23 L * ?")
```

For **generate** or **check** corn expression use [*this*](http://www.cronmaker.com/)

Comment: But In my case L is not supporting as a string in Spring

Answer (score 0):

You can also try with time zone

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 10 23 L * ?", zone = "CET")
public void scheduleTaskWithCronExpression() {
    System.out.println("Cron Task");
}
```

Comment: Is it mandatory to write zone. If we don't write what will happen?

Comment: no, it's not mandatory. if you don't pass zone it will work according to the application server zone.